# How can i show author post at listing page

Tags: wordpress, listings

I created a listing/directory theme to the wordpress. Theme is supporting add short code or static code (raw). i want to show recent blog post of only listing owner at all listing page. I can show recent post at listing page but showing all author's post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your dashboard sidebars options go to post and then open up the screen option, there you will see Columns heading , just check the box of author and the other which you want to show along with author post. As well as you can set numbers of post per page and also change the view mode.
By doing this you can only show the author post to your post section.